# In React Native, what would be the preferred way to play audio streams?

Tags: react-native

The HTML audio player API is the best way I've found in Cordova, i.e. not using any plugins, just emerging-standard Web technology.

Is there a polyfill for audio playing in React Native, or is there planned to be?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this moment, but React Native already has some polyfills and I would expect it will be added later because React Native is quite new technology.

If you need it now I would suggest using [the plugin from Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) and migrate it to React Native with help of [native modules](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content).